# Easiest way to sort DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have a list like this:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="list-item1">text 1</li>
    <li id="list-item2">text 2</li>
    <li id="list-item3">text 3</li>
    <li id="list-item4">text 4</li>
</ul>
```

What's the easiest way to re-arrange the DOM nodes to my preference? (This needs to happen automatically when the page loads, the list-order preference is gained from a cookie)

E.g.

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="list-item3">text 3</li>
    <li id="list-item4">text 4</li>
    <li id="list-item2">text 2</li>
    <li id="list-item1">text 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but if you're using a server side technology (like PHP) on this page, then it should also have access to the cookies. in PHP, it's in the global $_COOKIE array.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Though there's probably an easier way to do this using a JS Library, here's a working solution using vanilla js.

```
var list = document.getElementById('mylist');

var items = list.childNodes;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // get rid of the whitespace text nodes
        itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
}

itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML
          ? 0
          : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});

for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
  list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution NickF, I'm gonna adapt it a bit since I'm using jQuery but I think I have an idea of how to do it now, thanks! :)

Comment: By using `list.children` instead of `list.childNodes`, you can avoid the check for text nodes.

Comment: When I first read this answer, I thought vanilla js?  Why is [vanilla.js](http://vanilla-js.com/) required here?  :^)

Comment: @LivingstonSamuel ...but on the expense of not working in IE (even IE11!)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Looks like it's fully supported now.

Comment: The `sort` callback can be simplified to `(a, b) => a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML)` or `({ innerHTML: a }, { innerHTML: b }) => a.localeCompare(b)`. There are a few other more modern ways of writing a solution to this problem and other optimizations. Here’s a modern example: [sort div's through sort();](/a/75152213/4642212).

Answer (score 96):

You can use this to re-sort an element's children:

```
const list = document.querySelector('#test-list');

[...list.children]
  .sort((a, b) => a.innerText > b.innerText ? 1 : -1)
  .forEach(node => list.appendChild(node));
```

- [`list.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so we use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) introduced in ES6 to convert it to a standard array.
- We [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) this array with a [custom comparison function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_array_of_objects) that sorts by `innerText`.
- Every child is re-appended to `list` in the order of the now sorted array. When an element is re-appended it is actually moved from its previous location ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)), so after every element has been re-appended in sorted order we end up with a sorted `list`.

Comment: nice one! this is a clean way to do it.

Comment: Brilliant! Much the smartest way to reorder the nodes

Comment: This is best solution

Comment: It is a bit more correct semantically to use "forEach" method instead of "map" , as you're not interested in actual mapping of the elements in this case, you just want to call a callback with the side effect (attaching to another element).

Comment: Note: In case you want to use `parseFloat()` to sort by numbers make sure that you replace `NaN` with `0` or you ll not get correct sorting.

Comment: Perhaps good to note that `appendChild()` does not *actually* append the child, in this case. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild): *"Note: If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document,* `appendChild()` *moves it from its current position to the new position."*

Comment: @ahuigo Why do you prefer the opaque spread-syntax over the more descriptive `Array.from`?

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey **Spread syntax** is more efficient and simple at inputting than `Array.from`. I would recommend using `Array.from` as a supplement to the **Spread Syntax**.

Answer (score 25):

You might find that sorting the DOM nodes doesn't perform well.   A different approach would be to have in your javascript an array that represents the data that would go into the DOM nodes, sort that data, and then regenerate the div that holds the DOM nodes.

Maybe you dont' have that many nodes to sort, so it wouldn't matter.   My experience is based on trying to sort HTML tables by manipulating the DOM, including tables with hundreds of rows and a couple dozen columns.

Answer (score 13):

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/stefek99/y7JyT/

```
    jQuery.fn.sortDomElements = (function() {
        return function(comparator) {
            return Array.prototype.sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i) {
                  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
            });
        };
    })();
```

**Terse**

Comment: Nice! I also like things terse, so based on that, I came up with a [very simple jQuery function](http://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/H2mrp/) that lets you provide a callback-function that computes the value to sort by. (I included two examples: sorting a list alphabetically, and sorting a table by a numeric value in the first column - both essentially one-liners.)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but may i ask, what is the benefit of using a self executing function return the sortDomElements function? Wouldn't it be more terse to say jQuery.fn.sortDomElements = function(comparitor)... ? like this http://jsfiddle.net/y7JyT/77/

Answer (score 11):

My version, hope will be useful for others:

```
var p = document.getElementById('mylist');
Array.prototype.slice.call(p.children)
  .map(function (x) { return p.removeChild(x); })
  .sort(function (x, y) { return /* your sort logic, compare x and y here */; })
  .forEach(function (x) { p.appendChild(x); });
```

Comment: What do you mean `/* sort logic */`? :/  The code looks good, but my sort logic is a bit weak

Comment: It means you should put your sort logic there, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort it basically the same, only x and y are DOM nodes.

Answer (score 8):

If you're already using jQuery, I'd recommend tinysort : http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

```
$("li").tsort({order:"asc"});
$("li").tsort({order:"desc"});
```

Comment: Tinysort is multiple times slower than 13 lines of code, based on sorting jquery selection result and appending it back - http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-getattribute/12

Comment: TinySort used to be a jQuery plugin but was rewritten to remove the jQuery dependency. It is now smaller and faster

Answer (score 7):

Here's an ES6 function to sort DOM nodes in place:

```js
const sortChildren = ({ container, childSelector, getScore }) => {
  const items = [...container.querySelectorAll(childSelector)];

  items
    .sort((a, b) => getScore(b) - getScore(a))
    .forEach(item => container.appendChild(item));
};
```

Here's how you would use it to sort [Untapped user reviews by score](https://untappd.com/user/LukeTheLush):

```js
sortChildren({
  container: document.querySelector("#main-stream"),
  childSelector: ".item",
  getScore: item => {
    const rating = item.querySelector(".rating");
    if (!rating) return 0;
    const scoreString = [...rating.classList].find(c => /r\d+/.test(c));
    const score = parseInt(scoreString.slice(1));
    return score;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

without analyzing too much if this brings anything new to the table, i usually use this:

```
function forEach(ar, func){ if(ar){for(var i=ar.length; i--; ){ func(ar[i], i); }} }
function removeElement(node){ return node.parentNode.removeChild(node); }
function insertBefore(ref){ return function(node){ return ref.parentNode.insertBefore(node, ref); }; }

function sort(items, greater){ 
    var marker = insertBefore(items[0])(document.createElement("div")); //in case there is stuff before/after the sortees
    forEach(items, removeElement);
    items.sort(greater); 
    items.reverse(); //because the last will be first when reappending
    forEach(items, insertBefore(marker));
    removeElement(marker);
}
```

where item is an array of children of the same parent. we remove starting with the last and append starting with the first to avoid flickering in the top part which is probably on screen. i usually get my items array like this:

```
forEachSnapshot(document.evaluate(..., 6, null), function(n, i){ items[i] = n; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `appendChild` in a loop with a single call of `replaceChildren`. Also `localeCompare` might be convenient since it always returns 0, 1, or -1.

```js
const list = document.getElementById("mylist");
const children = Array.from(list.children).sort((a,b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent));
list.replaceChildren(...children);
```

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way I can think of:

The param `compare` is just like the compare function used in [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Sort child nodes.

```js
/**
 * @param {!Node} parent
 * @param {function(!Node, !Node):number} compare
 */
function sortChildNodes(parent, compare) {
  const moveNode = (newParent, node) => {
    // If node is already under a parent, append() removes it from the
    // original parent before appending it to the new parent.
    newParent.append(node);
    return newParent;
  };
  parent.append(Array.from(parent.childNodes) // Shallow copies of nodes.
                    .sort(compare) // Sort the shallow copies.
                    .reduce(moveNode, document.createDocumentFragment()));
}
```

Sort child elements (a subset of child nodes).

```js
/**
 * @param {!Element} parent
 * @param {function(!Element, !Element):number} compare
 */
function sortChildren(parent, compare) {
  const moveElement = (newParent, element) => {
    // If element is already under a parent, append() removes it from the
    // original parent before appending it to the new parent.
    newParent.append(element);
    return newParent;
  };
  parent.append(Array.from(parent.children) // Shallow copies of elements.
                    .sort(compare) // Sort the shallow copies.
                    .reduce(moveElement, document.createDocumentFragment()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need numerical sorting, here is the short solution that worked for me:
(if you need alphabetical sorting, just remove the two `+` in the function, I think it's still a shorter solution than the currently most upvoted ones)

```
function sortSelectOpts(selectNode) {
    const optionNodes = Array.from(selectNode.children);
    optionNodes.sort((a,b) => +a.innerText > +b.innerText ?1:-1);
    optionNodes.forEach((option) => selectNode.appendChild(option));
}
```

Which is to be used like this:

```
sortSelectOpts(document.getElementById('CircuitNumber'));
```