# php XPath reverse array

Tags: php, xpath

Hi there I am trying to reverse php object but I am not successful
sample html is here:
[sample_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B25T5.png)

```
$html = file_get_contents($file);

$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);


//get the element you want to append to
$classname = 'pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
var_dump($divs[0]);
$count = count($divs);
$divs2 = array();
for ($i = $count-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $divs = $divs[$i];
}
var_dump($divs[0]);
```

its giving  Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in

when I have this div reversed I would like to append it back to original html with something like

```
$doc->saveHTML();
```

TLDR: I can get the div but cannot reverse it

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: Why you re doing this. $divs = $divs[$i] ?                I guess you re trying to fill second array, if that's right you have to write $divs2[] = $divs[$i]

Comment: You need to remove the child nodes from the parent, reverse the order, then re-add them to the DOM.

Comment: Can you provide sample HTML? Are all the div elements you wish to "reverse" direct siblings and of the same parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I don't know if this meets your html structure requirements, but if all your divs are immediate siblings (like a list) and they all share the same parent, you can use the following.

```
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

for( $x = 0; $x < $divs->length ; $x++ )
{
  if( $divs[ $x ] !== $divs[ $x ]->parentNode->firstChild )
  {
    $divs[ $x ]->parentNode->insertBefore( $divs[ $x ], $divs[ $x ]->parentNode->firstChild );
  }
}
```

---

Alternative solution leveraging `iterator_to_array` and `cloneNode`

```
$divs = iterator_to_array( $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]") );
$keys = array_reverse( array_keys( $divs ) );
foreach( $divs as $x => $div )
{
  $div->parentNode->replaceChild( $divs[ $keys[ $x ] ]->cloneNode(true), $div );
}
```