# How do I rewrite this using if…else clauses?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

```
itemsArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML ? 0 : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});
```

I'd like to know how this function could be written with if & else syntax

Comment: FYI, that's *a* ternary operator, but its actual name is ‘conditional operator’.

Answer (score 3):

```
itemsArr.sort(sortFunction);
function sortFunction (a, b) { 
  if (a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML) return 0;
  else if (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) return 1;
  else return -1; 
}
```

Comment: @Yoni - as someone else pointed out, the else's are optional when you use return.

Answer (score 1):

That would look like this:

```
itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML) {
    return 0;
  } else if (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
});
```

You can also write it without `else`, as the `return` will exit the function:

```
itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML) return 0;
  if (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) return 1;
  return -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isGreater(a,b){
   if(a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML){
     return 0;
   } else if(a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML){
          return 1;
   }else{
       return -1;
   }
}
```

***But why you want to do this?***

Comment: Im learning about this subject and I saw this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282670/easiest-way-to-sort-dom-nodes/5854834#5854834

Comment: @YoniGeek: then you should comment @nickf about this rather than giving answer and then after asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(a, b) {
   returnType returnValue;

   if(a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML){
    returnValue = 0;
   }else if(a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML){
    returnValue = 1
   }else{
    returnValue = -1
   }

   return returnValue;
}
```