# How can I sort bulks of text within an accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion with many items in random sequence. How can I have these items sorted when the accordion loads:

```
< div class="accordion" >
    < h3>Abc </h3 > 
    < p>Some text. </p > 

    < h3>Cab </h3 > 
    < p>Some text. </p > 

    < h3>Bac </h3 > 
    < p>Some text. </p > 
< /div >
```

Comment: Sort them before you create the accordion.  Sorting with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282670/easiest-way-to-sort-dom-nodes

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some of your code. It isn't very clear what you want help with.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Include that plugin, run a sort on your accordion content. eg. if its in a ul list:

```
$('ul>li').tsort();
//its sorted, trigger your accordion plugin here
```

### Edit on more information

Ok so if you are not using a list, throw them into divs to isolate each section:

```
< div class="accordion" >
    <div class="section">
        < h3>Abc </h3 > 
        < p>Some text. </p > 
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        < h3>Cab </h3 > 
        < p>Some text. </p > 
    </div>
< /div >
```

Then sort by the h3 tag:

```
$('.accordion div.section').tsort('h3');
//then do your accordion code
```

Comment: I don use a list, I only use the < h3 > tag and < p > tag: like < h3 > ABC < /h3 > < p > Some text < /p>

Comment: Thanks, what should the class "section" look like?

Comment: Hi, I am not an experienced programmer and don't quite get how to use this. Could you please explain or give me a sample code to play with?

Comment: You dont need to apply any CSS to the class "section", its just to identify it for the jquery call. `$('.accordion div.section')` targets all divs with a class of section that are children of anything with the class of 'accordion'

Answer (score 0):

sort them before you create accordion is the easiest way