# set a newly created div on top of the older divs

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a bunch of divs inside a container. The position of the content divs is relative, because I want them to appear one below the other and their height is unknown.

These divs are created dynamically (appendchild) inside the container div. Now, each div appears on the end (bottom) of the stack but my requirement is that the divs have a "newest first" option too, that is, each new div appears on top, not on bottom of the content divs (if the user selects the "newest first" in the settings).

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1" class="content">aaa<br>aaa</div>
    <div id="div2" class="content">bbb<br><br>bbb</div>
    <div id="div3" class="content">ccc</div>
    <div id="div4" class="content">ddd</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jk559/1/

so I'd like the end-user visible order to be: div4, div3, div2, div1.

How can I achieve this? (css/js)

preferrably no jquery.

thanks in advice!

Comment: Why no jquery? Isn't it (as in @sriraman's answer below) often easier and/or neater?

Comment: The relative position doesnt do anything, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
theParent = document.getElementById("theParent");
theKid = document.createElement("div");
theKid.setAttribute("id","div5");
theKid.setAttribute("class","content");
theKid.innerHTML = 'eee';

// append theKid to the end of theParent
theParent.appendChild(theKid);

// prepend theKid to the beginning of theParent
theParent.insertBefore(theKid, theParent.firstChild);
```

Demo Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jk559/4/

Comment: thank you! That is a crossbrowser solution, and simply javascript, what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Pure css solution:

Use `flexbox` to achieve this.

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-content: flex-end;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/jk559/3/)

[Read more information here.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hiral, thank you very much, this is a very elegant solution. However due to this http://caniuse.com/flexbox and since I'd prefer a cross-browser solution (not even firefox has as of now a full support) I will prefer the insertbefore solution

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it with JQuery with the following function.

```
$('.container > div').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sriraman/jk559/2/)

As you mentioned in the question, I will try to attain the expected output with the pure javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert content in the beginning simply using [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) .

```
$(".container").prepend("<div id='div5' class='content'>eee</div>");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/Ey76N/)

Answer (score 2):

[JS FIDDLE UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jk559/5/)

Use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add as first child of an element

```
/* $( ".container" ).prepend( "Your div with id here" ); */
/* Example */

 $( ".container" ).prepend( "<div id='div5' class='content' >div5 on top </div>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282670/easiest-way-to-sort-dom-nodes) about reordering dom items.

Basically, you have to maintain a state that decides the ordering. When you insert items (see `insertItem` below) you append or prepend based on the state. When the user selects the newest first option (see `newFirst` below), you first reverse the dom elements  and then flip the state so that subsequent insert happen at the right place.

```
var newFirst = false;
var list = document.getElementById('my-list');

function newFirst() {      
    var items = list.childNodes;
    var itemsArr = [];
    for (var i in items) {
        if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // get rid of the whitespace text nodes
            itemsArr.push(items[i]);
        }
    }

    itemsArr.reverse();

    for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
      list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
    }

    newFirst = !newFirst;
}

function insertItem(content) {
    var item = document.createElement("div");
    item.setAttribute("class","content");
    item.innerHTML = content;

    if(newFirst) {
        list.insertBefore(item, list.firstChild);
    } else {
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("div[id*=div]").sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.id > b.id) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}).each(function() { 
    var elem = $(this);
    $(".container").append(elem);
});
```

this will sort your divs inside container like this : `div4, div3, div2, div1`

if you want change the order to : `div1, div2, div3, div4` just change `if(a.id > b.id)` to `if(a.id < b.id)`

you can add a link called `change order` then call this code when you click on it