# JS Class List Not Working

Tags: javascript, filtering, blogger

so I am trying to make a page on my blog that has a list of the games that I have posts about and I am trying to make a filter to help people find games based on classes.  I am using buttons with onclick="myFuntion()" but for some reason I cant seem to get it to work.  I am pretty rusty with js but I think the logic is sound and should be working.

java script

```
function allFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter");

    if (filter.classList.contains("games_all")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false);
    }
}

function fpsFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter");

    if (filter.classList.contains("games_fps")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false);
    } else {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", false);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);
    }
}

function survivalFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter") {

    if (filter.classList.contains("games_survival")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false); 
    } else {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", false);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);
    }
}
```

From what I can tell this should be working but its not and I am about to give up and just leave the filter out if i cant figure this out soon.

PS sorry if I have formatted this post wrong, im new to the site.

EDIT: Here is one of the HTML items I am trying to filter.

```
<div class="separator" 
id="game_filter"
class="game_filter_show"
class="games_all" 
class="games_fps" 
style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a class="GameList" href="http://foo.com" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://foo.png /></a></div>
```

Here is the html for the buttons.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<span style="font-size: large;">
<button onclick="allFunction()">All Games</button>
<button onclick="fpsFunction()">First Person Shooters</button>
<button onclick="survivalFunction()">Survival Games</button>
</span></div>
```

Comment: There is no declaration for 'element' and there is a extra "{" in the last 
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter") {. Could you provide how you set class's on filter element?

Comment: @kodvin here is one of the items on the filter list.

Comment: all classes for one element should be placed in one attribute () class="separator game_filter_show games_all games_fps"

Comment: like i said there is no "element" definition in element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);  And i suspect you have multiple elements with same id

Comment: Please look at second plunker and if it is not what you want you should try to rephrase what and how you want your filtering to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this code and it looks it works, unless you want something else to be done.

```
    <div class="games_survival" id="game_filter"></div>
    <div id="element"></div>

    <div onclick="allFunction()">all</div>
    <div onclick="fpsFunction()">fps</div>
    <div onclick="survivalFunction()">survivval</div>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById("element");
function allFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter");

    if (filter.classList.contains("games_all")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false);
    }
}

function fpsFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter");

    if (filter.classList.contains("games_fps")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false);
    } else {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", false);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);
    }
}

function survivalFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("game_filter") ;

    if (filter.classList.contains("games_survival")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false); 
    } else {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", false);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);
    }
}
</script>
```

and [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vhxdktCmKqfNqlqO4s5i?p=preview) is a plunk to show how it works

Maybe you filter items depending on classes placed on them, then

```
   <style>
  .game_filter_show {color: red; } 
  .game_filter_hide{background-color: blue;}
  </style>

    <div class="element games_survival">text in here1</div>
    <div class="element games_fps">text in here2</div>

    <div onclick="allFunction()">all</div>
    <div onclick="fpsFunction()">fps</div>
    <div onclick="survivalFunction()">survivval</div>

<script>
function allFunction() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("element");

      elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements,0);
    elements.map(function(element){
          element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
          element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false);
    })
}

function fpsFunction() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
      elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements,0);
    elements.map(function(element){
      if (element.classList.contains("games_fps")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false);
    } else {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", false);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);
    }    
    })
}

function survivalFunction() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
      elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements,0);
    elements.map(function(element){
      if (element.classList.contains("games_survival")) {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", true);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", false); 
    } else {
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_show", false);
        element.classList.toggle("game_filter_hide", true);
    } 
    })
}
</script>
```

and another [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PmI845xXsNUN830iJSlb?p=preview)
EDIT: remove games_all class checking, or you could add games_all o every item in the list, but this would be easier.

Comment: This Second one is what I am trying to do. I changed the styes to display: block and display: none and it worked like a charm. The one problem is that when I click on the all button it is supposed to make all of the divs show but nothing happens. Also what is the class="blue" for?

Comment: ouh sorry, it was for testing. will remove it

Comment: updated the answer and second plunker, you should either remove "games_all" checking or add this class to every element. I hope it helps

Comment: Ok so i used the new version of the second code it it works fine the way you wrote it but when I implemented it on my blog it doesnt work at all.

Comment: Update: Instead of working your code onto what I already had I just scrapped it and started from scratch with the example for the base and it is working now(well not on mobile but what ever). On another note I was just wondering if you had any ideas on how I could automatically sort the links once I start rating them so the higher the rating the closer to the top they would be.

Comment: So if i helped please accept the answer and maybe plus it. And for sorting its another question and a duplicate one and you can find answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282670/easiest-way-to-sort-dom-nodes