# JS sort parent element based on child element

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

I want to sort my JavaScript divs on their child values (span content).

I already found here a sorting algorthm for javascript on this thread:
[Easiest way to sort DOM nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282670/easiest-way-to-sort-dom-nodes)

However it is only for simple list. I want to have a modified version which don't look on the paragraph elements.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="myclass">
    <p class="hide">1</p>
    <span>2</span>
  </div>

  <div class="myclass">
    <p class="hide">2</p>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="myclass">
    <p class="hide">3</p>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="myclass">
    <p class="hide">4</p>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var list = document.getElementById('sortme');

var items = list.childNodes;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
    // HERE I need to get to the SPAN Element but how?
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // get rid of the whitespace text nodes
        itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
}

itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML
          ? 0
          : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});

for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
  list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhpe7vov/).

Comment: Show us your DOM structure as markup, please.

Comment: Actually, it's even easier in your case, as there's a solid criteria for items to be rearranged - className. So 1) replace `list.childNodes` call with `list.querySelectorAll('.myclass')`, and 2) check `a.querySelector('span').innerHTML` against `b.querySelector('span').innerHTML` instead (it might be better memoizing this stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/td3qu3eq/)):

```
var list = document.getElementById('sortme');

var nodesToSort = list.querySelectorAll('.myclass');

Array.prototype.map.call(nodesToSort, function(node) {
  return {
    node: node,
    relevantText: node.querySelector('span').textContent
  };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.relevantText.localeCompare(b.relevantText);
}).forEach(function(item) {
  list.appendChild(item.node);
});
```

As you noticed, there are several changes here.

First, as I said, you don't need to use `root.childNodes`, as all the items that should be sorted are easily collected with either `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassname` method (I choose the former, mainly for consistency reasons). That also makes `nodeType`-based filtering redundant.

*(actually, it would have been redundant in the link answer too, had the author used `children` property instead of `childNodes`)*

Second, the sorting-helper array now contains not just nodes, but objects; the purpose of this technique - also known as [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) - is to minimize the sheer quantity of DOM queries, enhancing the performance.

*(here I have replaced `innerHTML` query with `textContent`, as you seem to be interested only in text here, ignoring any inline tags within the `<span>`. If that's not the case, just replace it back)*

Finally, another change from the original: replacing double comparison (first `==`, then `>`) with simple string function - [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), specifically designed for, well, comparing the strings.

And, of course, now the whole process is structured as a chain of operations:

- organizing the array of items alongside their memoized sorting criteria
- sorting this array
- (re)appending the nodes from that array into the list

... without any need of intermediate variables and stuff.

---

It's not clear whether the structure is uniform (i.e., do you always want to sort based on `<span>` contents). If you just want to sort based on *visible* text, consider using `node.innerText` instead of `node.querySelector('span').textContent`. Be aware, however: `innerText`, although supported by any modern browser, by definition is a slow, calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering the document order you could use flexboxes and the CSS [order:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to change their display order.